How do I install PeaZip on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS?
Walk me through this step by step, how do I install PeaZip on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS? And also please tell me how to uninstall it in case I want to get rid of it.

@user68186 The PeaZip website has completely changed compared to 2 years ago. The PeaZip website is totally different compared to 2 years ago and I need a new updated tutorial on how to install PeaZip for Ubuntu 24.04 believe me I tried to figure it out on my own and I couldn't so then I came here asking for help. I can't figure this out the new PeaZip website is a chaotic mess, it's not easy to understand at all. I'm stumped.

I have no idea what you mean here. The top answer says "Go to the PeaZip webpage and click PeaZip for Linux. [...] click either the DEB GTK2 link [...] or the DEB Qt5 link [...] and download the .deb package of your choice to the location of your choice." And if I got to https://peazip.github.io/, I can follow those instructions just fine. Even the screenshot is perfect except for the version number.

@muru Hey you know what, you're right, you're right indeed. I think I was just a little confused was all. It's just they changed their website around and I think it threw me off at first but yeah you're right indeed.

Try this:
Open a terminal and run:
cd ~/Downloads

wget https://github.com/peazip/PeaZip/releases/download/10.0.0/peazip_10.0.0.LINUX.GTK2-1_amd64.deb

sudo apt install ~/Downloads/peazip_10.0.0.LINUX.GTK2-1_amd64.deb

exit

To remove it:
Open a terminal and run:
sudo apt remove Peazip

sudo apt autoremove

exit

